# Jqgrid add and edit url is not working as expected

Tags: spring, jqgrid

i using jqgrid and spring controller for client server communication. I want to add 'url' for 'add form' and 'edit form'. I have done some code but i am facing two problem.
have some problem.

Jqgrid code :

```
        width : 400, 
        url: 'person/test', 
        top: 350, 
        left:400,
        editCaption:"Edit Employee",
        viewPagerButtons :false,
        closeOnEscape:true,
        model : true,
        closeAfterEdit : true,
        topinfo : 'Top Info Test Edit',
        bottominfo : "Footer Info",
        checkOnSubmit : true

        },

        {width:400, 
            url:'person/test2', 
            top: 350, 
            left:400, 
            addCaption : "Add Employee",
            closeOnEscape:true,
            drag : true,
            model : true,
            topinfo : 'Top Info Test',
            closeAfterAdd : true
        },
```

Controller looks like this :

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/person")
public class DataController {

  private int personId;
  private List<Person> people = new ArrayList<Person>();





  @RequestMapping(value="/test2", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  @ResponseBody
  public void addPerson(){
      System.out.println("Added");
  }

  @RequestMapping(value="/test", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  @ResponseBody
  public void testPerson(@RequestParam("person") Person obj){

      System.out.println("Edited");
  }
```

In this code i have two problem :

First Problem :

When i submit on add form then i got the following error .

```
error Status: 'Not Found'. Error code: 404
```

Second problem :

When i submit on edit button then firstly it hits 'test2' (addPerson) method and then come to 'test' testPerson. I am confused how request hit addPerson first and then move to testperson.

can anybody tell me what's wrong in this code.

Comment: Can you show us your completed code that composing jQgrid? Have you find any console errors in your browser window?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use RequestMethod.PUT for testPerson method. Use POST for creation and PUT for updating records.